# Spring Data JDBC Interface Projection with nested property

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I have this DTOs (data transfer object):

```
public record ProjectsDto(long id, String projectName, String contact, String fundingCode, LocalDate runtimeFrom,
                          LocalDate runtimeTo, String costUnit, String chapter, String unit, UsersDto users) {
}
```

and

```
public record UsersDto(long id, String userName, String firstName, String lastname) {
}
```

I have this repository:

```
@Query("select p.id, p.projectname, p.contact, p.funding_code fundingCode, p.runtime_from runtimeFrom, p.runtime_to runtimeTo, " +
            "p.cost_unit costUnit, p.chapter, p.unit, u.id users_id, u.username userName, u.firstname firstName, u.lastname lastName " +
            "from projects p " +
            "inner join users u on u.id = p.users_id " +
            "where p.id = :id")
    Optional<ProjectsDto> findByIdAndProjectTo(long id);
```

The `ProjectDto` gets populated with all the simple properties like `runtimeTo` for example.
But the embedded `users` being a `UserDto` won´t get populated.

Do i have an error in my repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply not supported at the moment.

Comment: Are there any plans on doing so? In the meantime i´ve solved it with a database view. By the way - keep up the good work. I´m using Spring Data JDBC in the first place - if i have the choice!